# ProgrammingError when running a SAP Hana query from python

Tags: python, hana

I connected to SAP Hana with sqlalchemy

```
_dsn='dsn'
conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc://@{dsn}'.format(dsn=_dsn)
engine = sa.create_engine((conn_str)
```

Then I have a python file using a run() function.

```
def run(engine):
    """
    TBD
    """

    query = 
          """
        SELECT
           "CalendarDay",
           "Score"
        FROM "Table"
        WHERE  "PEvent" = ''H'' OR "PEvent" = ''T''
        ORDER BY "CalendarDay" DESC, "Score" ASC
            """
    result = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
    return result
```

Here is the 2 error message I get:

```
ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB SO][HDBODBC] Syntax error or access violation;257 sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "H": line 5 col 25 (at pos 328) (257) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

and

`ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB SO][HDBODBC] Syntax error or access violation;257 sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "H": line 15 col 25 (at pos 328) (257) (SQLExecDirectW)') [SQL: '\n        SELECT\n         "CalendarDay",\n         "Score",\n         FROM "Table"\n    WHERE  "PEVENT" = \'\'H\'\' OR "PEVENT" = \'\'T\'\'\n  ORDER BY "CalendarDay" DESC, "Score" ASC\n`      ']

My guess is that those back slash next to the H and T are creating this issue.
Since we have a ' at the beginning of the query then the ' in front of \'H close the string.

Unfortunately, I can't find the proper way to write my python code so SAP Hana can read it.

Comment: Have you tried just having one single quotation mark around the `H`  and the `T`? Repeating them usually is done in SQLSCRIPT Code where all strings need to be enclosed in `'` so that single quotes inside a string need escaping.

Comment: Why havent you used the sqlalchemy dialect for HANA to do this? [https://github.com/SAP/sqlalchemy-hana]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a different way to connect that handle this issue.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(DSN='dsn')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

This connection handle string issue in the query.